# when testing my hardhat configjs i find this problem what's the problem and how to resolve it please?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, hardhat

```
:\Users\DELL\nft_marketplace>npx hardhat test
```

Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

- Invalid account: #0 for network: mumbai - Expected string, received function
- Invalid account: #0 for network: mainnet - Expected string, received function

To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH8 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.